# EXCEL VBA - Copying columns that match a condition from one worksheet to a formatted worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very familiar with `vlookup`, pivot tables, but feel like this can be accomplished with `VBA`.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

`Sheet 1`: data sheet with headers. 
`Sheet 2`: summary sheet that is formatted with a specific look and data can only be pasted into the sheet starting at `row 10`.

- In `sheet 2, B5`, has a drop down list that allows you to select a name.
- I want someone to be able to check if the value in `Sheet 2 B5`, matches up `Sheet 1 Column A`.
- then the code will go back to the data sheet (`sheet 1`) and check in `column A` if it matches `Sheet 2 B5`.
- If `Sheet 2 B5`, matches `Sheet 1` `Column A`, then copy `Sheet 1` columns `B, C, D, E, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y`, that match `Sheet 2 B5` value, INTO `sheet 2` starting at `row 10`.

other notes
- Formats from `Sheet 1` cannot be copied into `Sheet 2`. I just need the contents. 
- the button to run the code is on `sheet 2`. (thus `sheet 2` is the active sheet at the time the macro runs).

My code so far...

```
Sub Report ()
Dim finalrow As Integer, i as Integer, name as String
Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A10:N29").ClearContents
name = Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("B5").Value
For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Cells(i, 1) = name Then
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 25)).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

But I keep getting

> runtime error 9.

Comment: You  need to avoid from selecting and activating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run-time error mostly happens due to not properly addressing cells. If you use explicit coding you are less likely to get these errors and also your code would be easily legible. Also use comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Report ()

 'Declare variables
  Dim name as String
  Dim wsh1 As Worksheet, wsh2 As Worksheet
  Dim erow As Long, i as Long

 'Set the sheets
  Set wsh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
  Set wsh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")

 'clean destination worksheet
  wsh2.Range("A10:N29").ClearContents

  name = wsh2.Range("B5").Value 'condition for copying

 'loop over reference sheet
  For i = 2 To wsh1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

    'Check if the row meets the condition
    If wsh1.Cells(i, 1) = name Then 

      wsh1.Range(wsh1.Cells(i, 2), wsh1.Cells(i, 25)).Copy 'copy the row

      erow = wsh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 'find last row in wsh2 

      wsh2.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'paste only values

    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

## Update:

As OP mentioned that it should be always at row 10, then this would be a better approach than using last row:

At the beginning of the code and outside the for loop define `erow = 10`. Then your if-block should be like this:

```
If wsh1.Cells(i, 1) = name Then 'Check if the row meets the condition

  wsh1.Range(wsh1.Cells(i, 2), wsh1.Cells(i, 25)).Copy 'copy the row

  wsh2.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'paste only values

  erow = erow + 1

End If
```

Comment: Masoud, thank you so much! I was looking into the Option Explicit but was unsure since I've never tried it before. Really appreciate your help. 

One question: 

After taking your approach, the values I need copy beneath my formatted cells, not within them (regardless its great that it works!). But, would this be occurring if my formatted cells are protected?

Comment: @MAJ10 I am not sure if I got your question. *After taking your approach, the values I need copy beneath my formatted cells, not within them (regardless its great that it works!)* What do you mean?

Comment: On sheet 2, I've formatted the entire sheet already so that it isn't just a blank worksheet. For some reason, the values are pasted into Sheet 2 starting at row 30. 

Rows 1 to 29 on Sheet 2 have formatting. I was hoping to understand how to get the values pasted starting at Row 10 instead of Row 30. 

Hope this makes sense... thank you!!

Comment: @MAJ10 is this always gonna start at row 10? And they are only formatted but not filled, not even with spaces, right?

Comment: Yes always at row 10 on sheet 2. They are only formatted, and are completely empty.